# C#: Datagrid get values

Tags: c#, datagridview, datagrid

I recently started my project for a personal app.

I have a DataGridView (bit of searching told this suites more good to my app), called ms_trans.

What I want to do with it, to load into a for cycle, and GET ALL ROW into a method.

```
    private void saveToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string srt = "";
        for (int i = 0; i >= ms_trans.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            not_mess.Text += (string)ms_trans.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value;
```

This is my for cycle. The problem is, I don't know why it gaves me 0 values. (I'm not stupid, I entered values all the time).
When I specified whic row and column value I want to get it gave back values properly.

Is it the string appending causing null values? Or what? I'm really stucked here.

PS.: I want to save the rows into a *.txt file, but even if I can't get the values. ONLY *.txt FILE IS ACCEPTABLE! Just help me out with getting values....

Comment: it should be < instead of >= in `for` loop: for(int i = 0; i < ms_trans.Rows.Count; i++)

Comment: Yeah it works but the last value is missing

Comment: could you update your question and explain that better, please. which last value is missing?

Comment: Make sure *the last value* cell's `IsInEditMode` property is `False`, otherwise it wouldn't show the new value. If this isn't the case, we need more details to help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the Foreach loop, that suppose to garantee you itterate through all the rows:

```
private void saveToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    string srt = "";
    foreach (GridViewRow row in  ms_trans.Rows)
    {
        not_mess.Text += (string)row.Cells[1].Value;
    }
```

}

hope it'll help.